# Positioning an image after clear:both div

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Could someone tell me how to position an image after a clear both div, used after two floating divs?

I have uploaded the page to http://justinstephens.co and the problem is occurring with the 'Download Rate card' image, which I want to move up about 40 - 50 px ..... for some reason it seems to be stuck where it is.

Comment: With 'after' you mean next to it, horizontaly?

Comment: Where do you want to place it?

Comment: To just move it up, centred about 50px

Comment: you can give it a negative margin `margin-top:-50px`